# cellRenderer multi line <br/> and Line hight

Tags: ag-grid-react

I have 2 issues with ag-grid

1. My field has a ';' separator and I want to show in the cell each sentence on new line. for this I wrote a renderer:

```
const ServicesRenderer = (params: ICellRendererParams ) => { 
    return <span>{params.value.split(';').join('<br/>')}</span>;
 };
```

it just shows '`<br/>`' instead of ; but no new line

2. The line height in any cell is 40px. I changed in my css :

```
.ag-cell {
  line-height: normal;
}
```

but it doesn't make the lines smaller.

Can anyone help?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. I changed the renderer to: `return <div>{params.value.split(';').map(s => <><span>{s}</span><br /></>)}</div>;` and it works. not sure why.
2. I changed the defaultColDef to have  `cellStyle: { lineHeight: 'normal'}` and that did it. Again not sure why id did not work with a class.

Thank y'All :-)